# SQL where clause with two conditions on same column

Tags: sql

first question here. 
I have a SQL query that needs to verify the user has receive an 'open' email, but not a 'confirmation' mail. For this I join two tables (the one with the users data, and the one with the mail data).

```
select u.username, m.username, m.subjectDescription 
from users u 
inner join mails m on m.username = u.username + '@hotmail.com' 
where m.SubjectDescription like '%open%' 
and (m.subjectDescription not like '%confirmation%')
```

This query only show the mails with 'open', but if I check user by user most of them have already received the confirmation letter. I only need to retrieve those users who have receive the 'open' mail but not the 'confirmation' mail.

Comment: What is the exact full subject when user receives a confirmation? Is it possible for confirmation subject to have both these words `open` and `confirmation` in them?

Comment: Sunil, it's not possible for the subject to have both words.

Comment: sophiet, I have just posted an answer with explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should work, and it's very intuitive in it's logic.

**Query Explanation**

Since a user could have two records in mail table, if he or she has received open as well as confirmation letters, so we look for only those users who have an open letter but no confirmation letter. We use NOT EXISTS to make sure that user has received no confirmation letter.

```
SELECT u.username, 
       m.username, 
       m.subjectdescription 
FROM   users u 
       INNER JOIN mails m 
               ON m.username = u.username + '@hotmail.com' 
WHERE  m.subjectdescription LIKE '%open%' 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM   mails m1 
                       WHERE  m1.username = m.username
                              AND m1.subjectdescription LIKE '%confirmation%');
```

Comment: Thanks!! This really worked, thank you a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to group the data by user and use the having clause to filter on group level

```
select u.username
from users u 
inner join mails m on (u.username + '@hotmail.com') = m.username  
group by u.username
having sum(case when m.SubjectDescription like '%open%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when m.SubjectDescription like '%confirmation%' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Hi, i think this is not  working for me since the data i'm comparing are not numbers. Can that be? I've edited my question with some changes that may have been confusing.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to LEFT OUTER JOIN to `mail`  twice:

```
select u.usernum, open.usernum, open.subjectDescription 
from users u 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN mails open on 
        u.usernum = open.usernum AND
        open.subjectDescription like '%open%'
   LEFT OUTER JOIN mails conf ON
        u.username = conf.usernum AND
        conf.subjectDescription like '%confirmation%'
where open.usernum IS NOT NULL AND conf.usernum IS NULL
```

Optionally (there are many ways to do this) you could use an IN clause in your WHERE:

```
select u.usernum, open.usernum, open.subjectDescription 
from users u 
   INNER JOIN mails open on 
        u.usernum = open.usernum AND
        open.subjectDescription like '%open%'       
where u.usernum IN (SELECT usernum FROM mails WHERE conf.subjectDescription like '%confirmation%')
```

Or, using EXISTS with a correlated subquery:

```
select u.usernum, open.usernum, open.subjectDescription 
from users u 
   INNER JOIN mails open on 
        u.usernum = open.usernum AND
        open.subjectDescription like '%open%'       
where EXISTS (SELECT usernum FROM mails WHERE conf.subjectDescription like '%confirmation%' AND u.usernum = usernum)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For some reason, it' returns nothing (it should return near 113 users). I've changed some things in my question that may have been confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mails
             WHERE usernum = u.usernum
             AND SubjectDescription LIKE '%open%')
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mails
               WHERE usernum = u.usernum
               AND SubjectDescription LIKE '%confirmation%');
```

Comment: for some reason, this is not returning anything. I've edited the question to make it more understandable. Thanks!

Comment: @sophiet and did you change the condition with the one you posted now?: `usernum = u.usernum + '@hotmail.com'`?

Comment: Yes, I've realized that the other way I was trying to do it wasn't going to work, sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for your time.